# Rewrite rules priority

Tags: rewrite-rules, taxonomy

I'm created URL rules for my theme but some rules not applied in the correct order..

For example:

(1) This rule (with only one taxonomy) works fine:

```
/from/(.+?)/?$ => 'index.php?post_type=custom&from=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1)
```

(2) And this another rule, with two or more taxonomies, not working because, the first rule (1) apparently it has higher priority or the regular expression is not well built.

```
/from/(.+?)/to/(.+?)/?$ => 'index.php?post_type=custom&from=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '&to=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2),
```

I used "monkeyman rewrite analyzer" plugin to check my rules and this screenshot shows that this URL: .../from/madrid/to/toledo return the first rule instead the second.

What's wrong??

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say either change the order, put (2) before (1), or be more specific with the rules.

E.g.

```
from/([a-zA-Z]*)/?
```

Comment: If I change the regular expression, I get this message: *Regex is empty!* @sdexp

Comment: There are different websites to check regex's. This is one but there are others: https://regex101.com/

Comment: I meant to say that with the period "." you're matching everything, so you need to be more specific because the period will match "/" too.

Comment: You might need to escape the forward slash like this... 'from\/([a-z]*)\/?'

Comment: I changed the order of rules and apparently works fine!